# Concatenate a column alias with variable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently trying to concatenate a simple variable into my column alias. The expected output should look like **TEST_SAMPLE_COLUMN** however when I place the underscore it will assume the literal value of the variable as **TEST_VAL_SAMPLE_COLUMN** and prompt me a substitution value.

```
DEFINE TEST_VAL = "TEST";
/
Select SAMPLE_COLUMN as "&TEST_VAL_SAMPLE_COLUMN"
from sample_table
```

While I'm able to incorporate the underscore into the double quote string using '_' unfortunately I'm unable to find a way to escape the single quotes so the final output will be returned as **TEST_VAL'_'SAMPLE_COLUMN**

```
DEFINE TEST_VAL = "TEST";
/
Select SAMPLE_COLUMN as "&TEST_VAL'_'SAMPLE_COLUMN"
from sample_table
```

I've tried numerous **CONCAT** and **||** functions (similar to concatenating column names), unfortunately I'm finding this method to be a little more trivial when constructing a column alias.

I was seeing if anyone has come across this type of scenario before in ORACLE, and just sourcing out the best way to overcome this issue (if possible)?

Comment: You need to write dynamic SQL to do this -- meaning `execute immediate`.

Comment: So, what is the desired outcome - do you want to create a column name that will have embedded single-quotes in it? WHY?

Comment: Also: Why do you want to "escape" the single-quotes? If you run the code sample exactly as written in SQL\*Plus it should work as desired. What happens when you try - do you get an error? Does the query run but with a different column name? In my tests it should do exactly what you want, odd as it may be. Tested in SQL Developer (not sure why you have that tag too) and it works equally well there.

Comment: The proposed outcome should be TEST_VAL_SAMPLE_COLUMN with the underscore minus the single quotes. Basically my question is around formatting where I'm looking to pre-pend the variable and concatenate the column in order to generate my column alias.

The second example I've provided is close to what I'm looking to achieve, however just trying eliminate/escape the single quotes.

Comment: I was hoping I could achieve this through static SQL over dynamic as well. However it's sounding that this might not be possible?